# Are all sequential circuits based on cross-coupled NAND or NOR gates?

Tags: digital-logic

So far, all the sequential circuits I see in the textbook use cross-coupled NAND or NOR gates.  Is it possible to design a sequential circuit without them?

Comment: You could make a "sequential circuit" using relays; latching relays can be thought of as nonvolatile RAM, etc. But just because you can doesn't mean you should. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By sequential I assume you mean a (bit) storage cell?

A static storage cell must have two elements:

- positive feedback, to maintain a stable state forever
- an input that can overrule the feedback (in both directions!)

Cross-coupled NAND or NOR gates have both properties. (The cross-coupling is the positive feedback path.) There are more complex building blocks that can also have these properties (two multipexers for instance), but one could argue that those are themselves composed of NAND and NOR gates.

An other circuit that has this property is an amplifier (call it a non-inverting gate, or two inverters in series) with a weak feedback, and an input that can provide a strong drive to high or low (or be in high impedance, letting the feedback do its work). Whether this counts as a double NAND gate with feedback is IMO a philosophical question.

In the non-static world there are options that store something for a limited time, and then read it back before it fades away, and restore it to its original level. You could see this as a positive feedback loop in the time dimension. DRAMs work this way, but various older techniques too, like storage screens and mercury delay loops.

In the physical world there are some constructs that are bi-stable without an obvious feedback loop. Think of a ferrite core that can be magnetized in one of two directions, or a latching relay that uses a pulling coil to be stable in two positions. The essense here is that there are two lower-energy levels, separated by a high-energy barrier.

Within the digital world I think the answer to your question is YES, but the above examples shows that there are other implementations.

Comment: @vxs8122: on this site it is considered good practice two wait ~ 24 hour to give everyone (in all timezones) a decent chance to give an answer. You obviously think I gave a good answer, but someone might give an even better one :)

Comment: I understand. I will do that next time.

Answer (score 3):

Many CMOS logic designs (and also NMOS and PMOS designs, btw) make use of a circuit element called a "pass gate".  In its simplest form, a pass gate is simply a single NMOS or PMOS transistor (also called an NFET or PFET).  An NFET will connect is source and drain when the gate is high and disconnect when low; a PFET will connect the source and drain when the gate is low and disconnect when high.

Many circuits use single-transistor pass gates, but they have a major limitation: NFETs are not very good at pulling signals high, and PFETs are not very good at pulling them low.  Consequently, circuits which use a bunch of NFET-only pass gates to e.g. route one of several signals to an inverter may need to tweak the design of the inverter so that it will switch low if its input is even "kinda sorta" high.  Such tweaking may be worthwhile in some forms of high-density low-speed logic, but in general it's better to avoid relying upon the ability of an NFET to pull something high or a PFET to pull it low..

A more common style of pass gate uses a PFET and an NFET in parallel.  Such gates will conduct cleanly when the PFET input is low and the NFET input is high, and not conduct when the PFET input is high and the NFET input is low.  A good design will avoid relying upon the behavior of the pass gate at times when both inputs are high or both are low; in most cases, one will always be the inverse of the other.

Adding pass gates to one's repertoire will make it possible to construct many kinds of sequential circuits more compactly than would be possible using only inverters, NAND and NOR gates [an inverter requires two transistors, while NAND and NOR gates require two transistors per input; as noted, pass gates require one or two transistors].  A transparent latch which would require three NAND gates and a NOR for each bit, along with an inverter for the enable [which might be shared among many latches] may in many cases be replaced with two inverters, two pass gates, and a shareable inverter for the clock.  The former implementation would require sixteen transistors plus two for the clock; the latter would require eight.

Additionally, it's worth noting that it's possible to construct a gate with three or more inputs which combines NAND and NOR functions at a cost of two transistors per input; basically any function which represents the inversion of any combination of AND and OR gates, all of whose inputs are distinct, may be realized at a cost of two transistors per input of the circuit as a whole.  For example, a circuit that computed `not((A and B) or (C and D))` would have a total cost of eight transistors since there are four inputs.  By contrast, implementing that with NAND gates and inverters would require three two-input NAND gates and an inverter, for a total cost of fourteen.  A latch could be implemented with an inverter to compute `Q = not Qlo` and a hybrid gate which computes `Qlo = not (D and ClkHi) or (Q and ClkLo)`.  As with the pass gate latch, eight transistors plus a shareable inverter for the clock.

Answer (score 2):

NAND and NOR gates are the basic building blocks of all logic.

Using only NAND gates, or only NOR gates, you can create any other gate you want.  For instance, the Apollo Guidance Computer was created entirely out of NOR gates.

NAND and NOR are the only *common* gates* you can do this with since they have an inverting output and can be arranged by just tying the inputs together to form a NOT gate.  So two NAND gates can make an AND gate, but there is no way any number of AND gates can create a NAND gate.

For individual chips, how the manufacturer decides to implement the actual function (flip-flop, generic gate, multiplexer, etc) is entirely up to them.  They may decide upon a circuit that bears no resemblance to the equivalent circuit built entirely from NAND gates, since it may be more optimal to collapse multiple gates down into a smaller circuit (why have 2 inputs to a gate when you're only wanting to use 1?), but things like feedback connections (the cross-connecting you talk about) will still be in evidence in some form.

---

*Apparantly there's something called an "A and NOT B" gate, though I've never seen one.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question?

Comment: What I mean is, is it possible to somehow create a memory element without using the "cross-coupling" concept?  Or is it the foundation of all sequential circuits?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen It partially answers the question because  it explains why (not just states) that any logic circuit can be made up of NANDs or NORs.  Granted, he doesn't discuss the sequential circuits.

Comment: I would argue that NOT and OR gates are the basic building blocks of all logic as anything else can be built from them (including NAND and NOR gates) and are fundamentally simpler. You could also use NOT and AND gates, I suppose.

Comment: `NAND and NOR are the only [...]` not true. They are both types of *universal* gates, which also include things like A-and-NOT-B (example: 555 timer IC).

Answer (score 2):

The Short Answer is *YES* it is possible and indeed it is very common to NOT use cross-coupled Gates.  In fact most active circuits (in the form of microprocessors, SOC's ASIC's etc.) do not use this form (cross-coupled) of latch or memory.

The absolute minimum requirement for a memory cell is hysteresis, and in designs that only use transistors the easiest form of memory is to use feedback.  A cross-coupled design is just one form of feedback that is static.  There are many other forms that either are dynamic or use other forms of feedback to sustain the static signal.

The fundamental building block of logic is transistors.  If you think that the fundamental block is the NOR or NAND gate then you will think that the only way to build a register is to cross couple gates.  In fact most flip-flops and registers and latches (by number that have been produced) are never a cross coupled gate level design.

Certainly in undergraduate text books/courses, the cross coupled design is the easiest to teach.  I suspect that is because it doesn't require transistor knowledge.  Advanced designs are typically only in the graduate level courses.

The basic latch that is based upon feedback is the "busholder" design:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCTaqp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I drew this as purely an existence proof.  It is a lousy design but ... it uses only 6 transistors vs. a latch formed from NOR's which uses 8, will have less shoot through current and is more efficiently laid out.  The key here is to make some of the feedback transistor Long so they don't fight the set and rest so hard.  But that is a matter of tuning.

In general a gate based cross-coupled design will always have more transistors, consume more power on switching and be less compact in layout.

In fact, in evaluating third party libraries for IC design I check the layouts of the cells, for the flipflops and registers etc.  If they are cross coupled gate type I usually pass or replace them with better designs.

Now on to the real reason I wrote this ...

All the pictures below are from:
 "[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psjh1.png)   J. Yuan and C. Svensson, “New single-clock CMOS latches and flipflops with improved speed and power savings,” Solid-State Circuits, IEEE Journal of, vol. 32, no. 1, pp. 62–69, 1997."

and belong to a family of flip flops and latches that are called TSPC (True single phase clock).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You will notice that there arises in these circuits the cross-coupling that you noticed in the gate level designs.  That arises because of the need to prevent conflict between transistors in certain designs.

There are far more interesting designs in that paper and it has been seminal and highly referenced in design and academic work. It also provides the frame work for further developments.  It has influenced most modern IC design of memory elements.

Read it if you are interested.

But you must admit, there are some amazingly elegant solutions there.

And this is only one of many different approaches that are taken.

Answer (score 0):

If IC's were made using NANDs and NORs, there'd be a lot of wasted transistors. Nands and Nors *can* create any circuit, but there's almost always a better way that uses less transistors and space.

The basic D flip-flop implemented in CMOS technology is a prime example of this.
[image]

Compare that with the Nand implementation:
[image]

With each Nand taking up 4 transistors a-piece (not counting the 3-input Nands extra transistors) you'd end up with 24 transistors for the same functionality vs 12 in the typical CMOS implementation.

To answer your question, **yes** most digital integrated circuits would tend to steer away from cross-coupled nands because it's an inefficient use of transistors. The storage element in the case of the CMOS D flip-flop is the inherent capacitance of transistors. This small signal is then amplified by the topology of the transistors.

Comment: The CMOS flip-flop in that diagram is dynamic logic, which is not exactly universal. It's not DC-stable, and is thus not a true equivalent of the NAND implementation. It's still a good example of an alternative storage element, though.

Comment: @AdamHaun Agreed. Perhaps this isn't the best example.

Comment: Why the Down Vote?  This answers the question exactly and is actually closer to reality that most of the other questions.

Answer (score 0):

"Cross-coupled" gates are not the only way to persist the state of a bit for a while, but they're very convenient because you can make them out of the same material as the rest of a chip, which makes them fast and power-efficient, and saves space.

Alternative methods include:

- op-amp with positive feedback
- delay lines, bucket brigade devices
- audio-frequency echo
- write to hard disk
- relay logic
- Resistive RAM
- core memory

The list goes on, limited only by your imagination and the kinds of performance penalties you're willing to suffer.

Comment: You've gone rather far afield with this answer. The OP is asking specifically about the memory elements used to construct sequential logic circuits.